# Devise for creating a User on Rails does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I created a migration for generating a User model through *Devise* like shown below:

```
  rails g devise User
```

and then I create some views through *Devise*:

```
  rails g devise:views
```

Now when I run *rails db:migrate* I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\andri\Desktop\hoagieShop\hoagieShop>rails db:migrate
== 20190202141046 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/db/migrate/20190202141046_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/db/migrate/20190202141046_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "email" varchar DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/db/migrate/20190202141046_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/db/migrate/20190202141046_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: users
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/db/migrate/20190202141046_add_devise_to_users.rb:7:in `block in up'
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/db/migrate/20190202141046_add_devise_to_users.rb:5:in `up'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is the code inside the migration:

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true

  end

  def self.down
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

Does anyone understand why this happens? I appreciate any help!

Comment: table "user" already exists seems to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
rake db:drop 
rake db:create 
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: A more detailed explanation of your code would make it easier for the question asker to understand what you are trying to convey. I would suggest going back an adding additional detail as to why this is the right answer for the question. It would also provide greater clarity for other users who may be experiencing similar problems.

Comment: @adarsh this does not work. I get an error saying: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/db/development.sqlite3
Couldn't drop database 'db/development.sqlite3'
rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ unlink_internal - C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/db/development.sqlite3

Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe